# Is there any way to obtain high resolution images similar to RGB True colour images from Sentinel's SAR-C SAR data?

Tags: sentinel-1

Is there any methods which I could use to obtain any good quality true colour images from Sentinel 1 SAR Data?

Comment: It is synthetic aperture radar (SAR) representing the reflectance and back-scatter of electromagnetic waves. The resulting data are voxels of waveforms. There is no spectral content, why would you expect a true color image?

Comment: I was not expectng an aerial image...but rather a representation of landforms and landuse patterns that would be an alternative when the images from Sentinel 2 have cloud cover over 25%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True color images can only be obtained from optical sensors that detect visible light reflected off the Earth's surface. As @jeffrey-evans mentions in the comments, Sentinel 1 is a SAR sensor, which does its measurements using completely different wavelengths.

The measurements are rich enough, however, that they can be combined into several colour composites, which can help you identify patterns on the surface.

I've made an example with EO Browser, combining VV and VH bands into a colour image that has green-ish land and blue water ([you can explore the image in more detail yourself](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/#lat=-8.298130568878415&lng=114.62688446044922&zoom=12&time=2018-01-24&preset=CUSTOM&datasource=Sentinel-1%20GRD%20IW&layers=VH,VH,VH&evalscript=cmV0dXJuIFsKICAwLjEqTWF0aC5sb2coVkgpKzAuNiwKICAwLjEqTWF0aC5sb2coVlYpKzAuNSwKICAwLjA1Kk1hdGgubG9nKChWVi1WSCkvKFZWK1ZIKSkrMC4zXTs%3D)). I used VH for red, VV for green and (VV-VH)/(VV+VH) for blue components of the output.

[image: Colour composite of VV and VH SAR data. ©Copernicus Sentinel-1 data 2018 processed by Sentinel Hub]
*<sup>©Copernicus Sentinel-1 data 2018 processed by Sentinel Hub</sup>*